# How can I create an animated (rounded) rectangular border around my widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How can animate the border of a widget from 0 to 100% (similar to the Trim Path effects one can create in Adobe AfterEffects)? I want to apply this to widgets that have a rectangular or rounded rectangle shape.

Here's an example of the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The big picture:

Let's wrap the widget in a `CustomPaint`. Since the `CustomPaint` takes its child's size, we don't have to worry about painting at the correct position.

We can further take this wonderful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233047/12393365) for generic path animations as a starting point and tweak the code so that our `AnimatedBorderPainter` can paint paths for rectangles, rounded rectangles and circles.

Finally, we create an `AnimationController` and define the duration, curve and all other properties that we need.

## The details:

In the `paint` method of the `AnimatedBorderPainter` we first create the `_originalPath` (i.e. the complete path) when the animation starts and then subsequently (re)draw the `currentPath` based on the animation's progress. The `_createAnimatedPath` method is taken from the above-mentioned answer where it is described in greater detail.

```dart
  late Path _originalPath;
  late Paint _paint;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final animationPercent = _animation.value;

    // Construct original path once when animation starts
    if (animationPercent == 0.0) {
      _originalPath = _createOriginalPath(size);
      _paint = Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = _strokeWidth
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = _strokeColor;
    }

    final currentPath = _createAnimatedPath(
      _originalPath,
      animationPercent,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(currentPath, _paint);
  }
```

Let's focus on creating the original path for our shapes. We can use `addRect` (rectangle), `addRRect` (rounded rectangle) and `addOval` (circle) to create the respective shapes:

```dart
Path _createOriginalPath(Size size) {
    switch (_pathType) {
      case PathType.rect:
        return _createOriginalPathRect(size);
      case PathType.rRect:
        return _createOriginalPathRRect(size);
      case PathType.circle:
        return _createOriginalPathCircle(size);
    }
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      )
      ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2));
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(
          originalPath, PathType.rect, size);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
          _radius,
        ),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.rRect);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathCircle(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.circle);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }
```

Since we also want to define where our path animation starts (using the `startingPercentage` parameter), we have to cut and rejoin our originally constructed path based on the input:

```dart
  Path _createPathForStartingPercentage(Path originalPath, PathType pathType,
      [Size? size]) {
    // Assumes that original path consists of one subpath only
    final pathMetrics = originalPath.computeMetrics().first;
    final pathCutoffPoint = (_startingPercentage / 100) * pathMetrics.length;
    final firstSubPath = pathMetrics.extractPath(0, pathCutoffPoint);
    final secondSubPath =
        pathMetrics.extractPath(pathCutoffPoint, pathMetrics.length);
    if (pathType == PathType.rect) {
      Path path = Path()
        ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
        ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2))
        ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
      switch (_startingPercentage) {
        case 25:
          path.lineTo(size!.width + _strokeWidth / 2, 0);
          break;
        case 50:
          path.lineTo(size!.width - _strokeWidth / 2, size.height);
          break;
        case 75:
          path.lineTo(0, size!.height + _strokeWidth / 2);
          break;
        default:
      }
      return path;
    }
    return Path()
      ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
      ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
  }
```

Although there is still a little more to it (see full code below), we can then basically use our `AnimatedBorderPainter` as follows, defining things like the `startingPercentage`, the `animationDirection` and the `radius` (the latter being only relevant for rounded rectangles):

```dart
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: AnimatedBorderPainter(
              animation: _controller1,
              strokeColor: Colors.black,
              pathType: PathType.rRect,
              animationDirection: AnimationDirection.clockwise,
              startingPercentage: 40,
              radius: const Radius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Click me also!'),
              onPressed: _startAnimation1,
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Full code including example animations you can run in DartPad:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Border Animation',
        home: Scaffold(body: ExampleAnimatedBorderPainter()));
  }
}

// Example code including two animations
class ExampleAnimatedBorderPainter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ExampleAnimatedBorderPainter> createState() =>
      _ExampleAnimatedBorderPainterState();
}

class _ExampleAnimatedBorderPainterState
    extends State<ExampleAnimatedBorderPainter> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller1;
  late AnimationController _controller2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller1 = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 2000,
      ),
    );
    _controller2 = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 1500,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller1.dispose();
    _controller2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startAnimation1() {
    _controller1.reset();
    _controller1.animateTo(1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  void _startAnimation2() {
    _controller2.reset();
    _controller2.animateTo(1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: AnimatedBorderPainter(
              animation: _controller1,
              strokeColor: Colors.black,
              pathType: PathType.rRect,
              animationDirection: AnimationDirection.clockwise,
              startingPercentage: 40,
              radius: const Radius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Click me also!'),
              onPressed: _startAnimation1,
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: AnimatedBorderPainter(
              animation: _controller2,
              strokeColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              pathType: PathType.rRect,
              animationDirection: AnimationDirection.counterclockwise,
            ),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Click me also!'),
              onPressed: _startAnimation2,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> _animation;
  final PathType _pathType;
  final double _strokeWidth;
  final Color _strokeColor;
  final Radius _radius;
  final int _startingPercentage;
  final AnimationDirection _animationDirection;

  AnimatedBorderPainter({
    required animation,
    PathType pathType = PathType.rect,
    double strokeWidth = 2.0,
    Color strokeColor = Colors.blueGrey,
    Radius radius = const Radius.circular(4.0),
    int startingPercentage = 0,
    AnimationDirection animationDirection = AnimationDirection.clockwise,
  })  : assert(strokeWidth > 0, 'strokeWidth must be greater than 0.'),
        assert(startingPercentage >= 0 && startingPercentage <= 100,
            'startingPercentage must lie between 0 and 100.'),
        _animation = animation,
        _pathType = pathType,
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        _strokeColor = strokeColor,
        _radius = radius,
        _startingPercentage = startingPercentage,
        _animationDirection = animationDirection,
        super(repaint: animation);

  late Path _originalPath;
  late Paint _paint;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final animationPercent = _animation.value;

    // Construct original path once when animation starts
    if (animationPercent == 0.0) {
      _originalPath = _createOriginalPath(size);
      _paint = Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = _strokeWidth
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = _strokeColor;
    }

    final currentPath = _createAnimatedPath(
      _originalPath,
      animationPercent,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(currentPath, _paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(AnimatedBorderPainter oldDelegate) => true;

  Path _createOriginalPath(Size size) {
    switch (_pathType) {
      case PathType.rect:
        return _createOriginalPathRect(size);
      case PathType.rRect:
        return _createOriginalPathRRect(size);
      case PathType.circle:
        return _createOriginalPathCircle(size);
    }
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      )
      ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2));
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(
          originalPath, PathType.rect, size);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathRRect(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
          _radius,
        ),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.rRect);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createOriginalPathCircle(Size size) {
    Path originalPath = Path()
      ..addOval(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      );
    if (_startingPercentage > 0 && _startingPercentage < 100) {
      return _createPathForStartingPercentage(originalPath, PathType.circle);
    }
    return originalPath;
  }

  Path _createPathForStartingPercentage(Path originalPath, PathType pathType,
      [Size? size]) {
    // Assumes that original path consists of one subpath only
    final pathMetrics = originalPath.computeMetrics().first;
    final pathCutoffPoint = (_startingPercentage / 100) * pathMetrics.length;
    final firstSubPath = pathMetrics.extractPath(0, pathCutoffPoint);
    final secondSubPath =
        pathMetrics.extractPath(pathCutoffPoint, pathMetrics.length);
    if (pathType == PathType.rect) {
      Path path = Path()
        ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
        ..lineTo(0, -(_strokeWidth / 2))
        ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
      switch (_startingPercentage) {
        case 25:
          path.lineTo(size!.width + _strokeWidth / 2, 0);
          break;
        case 50:
          path.lineTo(size!.width - _strokeWidth / 2, size.height);
          break;
        case 75:
          path.lineTo(0, size!.height + _strokeWidth / 2);
          break;
        default:
      }
      return path;
    }
    return Path()
      ..addPath(secondSubPath, Offset.zero)
      ..addPath(firstSubPath, Offset.zero);
  }

  Path _createAnimatedPath(
    Path originalPath,
    double animationPercent,
  ) {
    // ComputeMetrics can only be iterated once!
    final totalLength = originalPath
        .computeMetrics()
        .fold(0.0, (double prev, PathMetric metric) => prev + metric.length);

    final currentLength = totalLength * animationPercent;

    return _extractPathUntilLength(originalPath, currentLength);
  }

  Path _extractPathUntilLength(
    Path originalPath,
    double length,
  ) {
    var currentLength = 0.0;

    final path = Path();

    var metricsIterator = _animationDirection == AnimationDirection.clockwise
        ? originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator
        : originalPath.computeMetrics().toList().reversed.iterator;

    while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
      var metric = metricsIterator.current;

      var nextLength = currentLength + metric.length;

      final isLastSegment = nextLength > length;
      if (isLastSegment) {
        final remainingLength = length - currentLength;
        final pathSegment = _animationDirection == AnimationDirection.clockwise
            ? metric.extractPath(0.0, remainingLength)
            : metric.extractPath(
                metric.length - remainingLength, metric.length);

        path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
        break;
      } else {
        // There might be a more efficient way of extracting an entire path
        final pathSegment = metric.extractPath(0.0, metric.length);
        path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
      }

      currentLength = nextLength;
    }

    return path;
  }
}

enum PathType {
  rect,
  rRect,
  circle,
}

enum AnimationDirection {
  clockwise,
  counterclockwise,
}
```