# How to do trajectory animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm looking for trajectory animation just like how https://leo9studio.com/ has done. You see while scrolling, those balls get scrolled from top to bottom. How can we replicate exactly in Flutter Web?

Additionally, how to create such a smooth scrolling effect in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

rive.app would be a good place to start looking, since you aren't really providing any context or code other than just a random idea, they have a great community and I have used their packaged for some neat animation on my web apps. They have a way to create your own designs and animations which would probably be the case there, unless you wanted to make it all with code then that would be a different story.

Or look at this post here [How to animate a path in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978603/how-to-animate-a-path-in-flutter)